# PyQt - QWebEnginePage

Tags: python, python-3.x, qt, парсер, pyqt5

Есть парсер:

```
class AppWindow(QtWidgets.QMainWindow):
    def __init__(self):
        QtWidgets.QMainWindow.__init__(self)
        #...
    def start(self):
        self.thread1 = parser()
        t = threading.Thread(target=self.thread1.run)
        t.daemon = True
        t.start()
    #...

class parser(QtCore.QThread):
    def __init__(self):
        super(parser, self).__init__()
        QtCore.QThread.__init__(self)
        #...
    def run(self):
        #...
        data = [...]
        queue = mp.Queue()
        for i in data:
            queue.put(i)
        processes = [mp.Process(target = parse_data, args=(queue)) for i in range(10)]
        for process in processes:
            process.daemon = True
            process.start()
        #...

def parse_data(data):
    for elem in data:
        def parse_elem(elem):
            #...
            html = Client(elem['url'])
            #...
        p = ThreadPool(processes = 1)
        try:
            p_result = p.apply_async(parse_elem, (elem))
            res = p_result.get(timeout=60) # поток создаётся только для того, чтобы установить таймаут на выполнение
            p.terminate()
            p.close()
        except:
            #...


class Client(QWebEnginePage): # source: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8049520/web-scraping-javascript-page-with-python#answer-51341435
    def __init__(self, url):
        global app
        print(url)
        self.app = QApplication(sys.argv)
        QWebEnginePage.__init__(self)
        self.html = ""
        self.loadFinished.connect(self.on_load_finished)
        self.load(QUrl(url))
        self.app.exec_()

    def on_load_finished(self):
        self.html = self.toHtml(self.Callable)

    def Callable(self, data):
        self.html = data
        self.app.quit()

def main():
    mp.freeze_support()
    app = QtWidgets.QApplication(sys.argv)
    appwindow = AppWindow()
    appwindow.show()
    sys.exit(app.exec_())


if __name__ == "__main__": 
    main()
```

Но вызов `Client` не работает, возвращая ошибку: `WARNING: QApplication was not created in the main() thread.`. Ещё не полностью разобрался, как всё устроено. Можно ли заставить `Client` работать?

Comment: Зачем вам `self.app = QApplication(sys.argv)`? Думаю проблема в том, что `QApplication` у вас больше чем 1. Да и странно, зачем вам его создавать в отдельном потоке?

Comment: @ Думаю проблема в том, что QApplication у вас больше чем 1
Да, так и есть. Можете предложить альтернативу? Желательно, с примером :)

Comment: Создайте один в `__main__`. Просто, не знаю зачем вам еще нужно

Comment: в таком случае, чем будет `self.app`?

Comment: Можно так `self.app = QApplication.instance()`. Но я не понимаю зачем вам это нужно. Можете объяснить? Может вам нужен не QApplication, а QCoreApplication?

Comment: @ Но я не понимаю зачем вам это нужно.
А каким образом можно её переработать?

Comment: Я так понял, что вы хотите создать несколько потоков, в каждом потоке цикл обработки событий через QApplication и QWebEnginePage для загрузки страниц с javascript'ом? Я таким извращением не занимался, поэтому сложно сходу вам посоветовать :) Кст, вот вопрос, связанный с вашей проблемом https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2798832/qapplication-in-non-main-thread

Comment: @ Я таким извращением не занимался, поэтому сложно сходу вам посоветовать

можете предложить альтернативный способ?

Comment: Смотря что вам нужно сделать. Какое условие задачи?

Comment: Задача состоит в том, чтобы получить всё содержимое страницы, включая тот контент, который будет подгружен js'ом, и вернуть его для дальнейшей обработки

Comment: Одной страницы?

Comment: каждому процессу будет дан список страниц, которые он должен обработать по одной

Answer (score 1, accepted):

У меня вот что получилось. На диск сохранило 5 файлов:

```
from PyQt5.QtWidgets import QApplication
from PyQt5.QtCore import QUrl
from PyQt5.QtWebEngineWidgets import QWebEnginePage


class Client(QWebEnginePage):
    def __init__(self, urls):
        self.app = QApplication([])

        super().__init__()

        self.response_list = []
        self.loadFinished.connect(self._on_load_finished)

        for url in urls:
            self.load(QUrl(url))
            self.app.exec_()

    def _on_load_finished(self):
        self.toHtml(self.callable)

    def callable(self, html_str):
        self.response_list.append(html_str)
        self.app.quit()


def go(urls):
    client = Client(urls)
    return client.response_list


if __name__ == '__main__':
    urls = [
        [
            'http://doc.qt.io/Qt-5/qwebenginepage.html',
            'https://yandex.ru/',
        ],
        [
            'http://doc.qt.io/Qt-5/qwebenginepage.html',
            'https://www.google.ru/',
        ],
        [
            'https://www.google.ru/',
        ]
    ]

    from multiprocessing import Pool
    with Pool() as p:
        results = p.map(go, urls)
        print(len(results))

    number = 1

    for result in results:
        print(len(result))

        for html in result:
            with open('result_{}.html'.format(number), 'w', encoding='utf-8') as f:
                f.write(html)

            number += 1
```

---

**P.S.** Я сначала [сделал синхронную версию](https://github.com/gil9red/SimplePyScripts/blob/751191e9cb18814edf0918c02d23321c9a0ecc66/qt__pyqt__pyside__pyqode/pyqt5__QWebEnginePage__Client_sync.py) в одном процессе, думал ее предложить, но после уточнения что нужно загружать несколько страниц и в разных процессах, то начал копать в сторону запуска `QApplication` в другом процессе. Поигравшийсь, сделал [пример с одним процессом-ребенком](https://github.com/gil9red/SimplePyScripts/blob/c0f8c2bd098dba53f694831a8ddaef225a23ad7d/qt__pyqt__pyside__pyqode/multiprocessing__QApplication__in_other_process.py), а потом и [с несколькими](https://github.com/gil9red/SimplePyScripts/blob/75d2876818a12a221b696d6307a452582caf33a9/qt__pyqt__pyside__pyqode/multiprocessing__QApplication__in_other_process_list__Pool_map.py). Это работало и это было круто. Ну, а взять синхронную версию и запустить в несколько процессов было уже не сложно.

Comment: Спасибо огромное! Немного переработал, и всё стало отлично! Разве что, смущают возвращаемые ошибки javascript'а. "js: Uncaught ReferenceError: AsyncSubject is not defined", "js: The SSL certificate used to load resources from https://widget.siteheart.com will be distrusted in the future.....". Можно ли с этим что-то сделать?

Comment: Такое ощущение что ошибки в самих страницах html -- т.е. там использовался js, а в нем ошибки, вот и ругается. Думаю, тут ничего не поделать

Comment: Понятно. Также достаточно часто появляются ошибки такого плана: "[...ERROR:cache_util.cc...] Unable to move cache folder C:\...\GPUCache to C:\...\old_GPUCache_000"
"[...ERROR:connection.cc...] Cookie sqlite error 5, errno 33: database is locked, sql: PRAGMA auto_vacuum" и другие, связанные с бд.

Не подскажите, насколько они "страшные"(могут ли каким-то образом повлиять на ход выполнения), из-за чего они могут возникать и можно ли как-то их предотвратить?

Comment: Похоже, когда несколько процессов запускалось они лезли в локальную базу данных sqlite, но один из процессов успевал с ней раньше других работать, блокируя доступ к ней другим. Судя по путям там они сохраняли/доставали кэшированные данных для GPU. Думаю, это не страшно, по идеи, если кэш не могут они взять, им придется запросить/сгенерировать актуальные данные. А так, я не знаю что тут еще сказать...

Comment: Ок, спасибо, что помогли